# Multiple service( Controller) in breezejs

Tags: javascript, uiviewcontroller, breeze

This below code for one controller

```
var serviceName = 'breeze/todos', // route to the Web Api controller
    manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
```

But i have many controller.  How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

The same above code can apply for as much Breeze controllers as you want.

File : `Todos-datacontext.js`

```
var serviceName = 'breeze/todos', // route to the Web Api controller
var   manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
```

File: `Accounts-datacontext.js`

```
   var serviceName = 'breeze/accounts', // route to the Web Api controller
    var   manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
```

etc...

Answer (score -1):

**Do not use several controllers**! Every EntityManager you create, fetches metadata - makes http request to associated controller **Metadata** method.

Instead create 1 controller and work only with it

You should use different controllers+EntityManagers only if you have different repositories

Comment: This is good advice that applies in most cases, and certainly should be considered before adding additional controllers. Although, I guess it should have been a comment - hence someone downvoted it.